# Bulk import of PrestaShop combinations

Tags: php, mysql, import, prestashop, bulkinsert

I need to import a massive amount (approx. 2.3 million) of attribute combinations to PrestaShop instance. Trying to import data via CSV files in parts of 3000 rows ends with server timeout.

Is there any simple way to import combinations in a reliable time? (except for writing own script that will put this data directly to MySQL database)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can't you just change your `max_execution_time` in php.ini ?

Comment: Why don't you want to insert your data directly in MySQL ?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre: I have no access to remote server configuration (shared hosting)

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre: I look for an automatic solution. Writing an import script that should maintain multiple PrestaShop tables will propably cause more problems and it will waste more time.

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting you can use php [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). If that's not what you're looking for, please had more informations to your question as it is currently too broad.

Comment: pull DB from server, configure localhost for long operations, import data on localhost, upload DB on server